# Passing User Input to EXE using "Start" and set priority

Tags: command-line, batch-file, priority

I have a batch file input.bat I use to start an executable and pass in user input like so:

```
foo.exe < userInput.txt
```

I would like to run foo.exe in a high priority mode, which I can successfully do by calling:

```
START "WindowName" /high "foo.exe"
```

However, if I try to call the batch file instead, the .exe does not run in high priority, e.g.

```
START "WindowName" /high "input.bat"
```

Is there way to pass my user input text to the .exe while using START to set the priority?

I've tested this out in both Powershell and the Command Prompt (run cmd) in Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise Version 10.0.19044 Build 19044